# Parsing json with nested arrays with Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am new to Gson parsing and did few basic Gson parsing. But this time my JSON is much complex. My JSON looks like :

```
{"uname":"man101",
"uid":"2",
    "account":{
            "entry":[8,15.48],
            "exit":[8,15.48],
            "details":
                [[0,0],[0,8.2],[1.15,8.2],[1.15,18.23],[7.33,18.23],[7.33,15.48],[12.15,2.28],
                [12.35,2.28],[12.35,0],[10.65,0],[10.65,1.42],[8.1,1.42],[8.1,3.95],
                [4.25,3.95],[4.25,0]],

            "section":
                [
                   {
                        "account":[[0,0],[0,3.35],
                            [4.25,3.35],[4.25,0]],
                            "category":"office",
                           "description":"Mobile based company",
                           "sectionname":"xyz",
                           "id":1
                  },

                  {
                        "account":[[0,3.95],[0,7.8],
                              [4.25,7.8],4.25,3.95]],
                        "category":"office",
                        "description":"Network based company",
                        "sectionname":"ABC",
                        "id":2
                  },
                ]
            },
    "category":"Cowork",
    "description":"Combined office space"
}
```

And I tried to parse this in following way

```
public class AccountData
{
    public String uname;
    public String uid;
    public String category;
    public String description;
    public Account account;

    public class Account
    {
        public float[] entry;
        public float[] exit;
        public List<float[]> details;
        public List<Section> section;
    }

    public class Section
    {
        public List<float[]> account;
        public String category;
        public String description;
        public String sectionname;
        public String id;
    }

}
```

And try to pass result like this

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 beaconList = gson.fromJson(result, AccountData.class);
```

It's run without any error but when I tried to access some data it gives null values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First** of all, your JSON is wrong, here is the corrected version (note for example the extra comma in line 9 of your code).

```
{
  "uname": "man101", 
  "uid": "2", 
  "account": {
    "entry": [
      8, 
      15.48
    ], 
    "exit": [
      8, 
      15.48
    ], 
    "details": [
      [
        0, 
        0
      ], 
      [
        0, 
        8.2
      ], 
      [
        1.15, 
        8.2
      ], 
      [
        1.15, 
        18.23
      ], 
      [
        7.33, 
        18.23
      ], 
      [
        7.33, 
        15.48
      ], 
      [
        12.15, 
        2.28
      ], 
      [
        12.35, 
        2.28
      ], 
      [
        12.35, 
        0
      ], 
      [
        10.65, 
        0
      ], 
      [
        10.65, 
        1.42
      ], 
      [
        8.1, 
        1.42
      ], 
      [
        8.1, 
        3.95
      ], 
      [
        4.25, 
        3.95
      ], 
      [
        4.25, 
        0
      ]
    ], 
    "section": [
      {
        "account": [
          [
            0, 
            0
          ], 
          [
            0, 
            3.35
          ], 
          [
            4.25, 
            3.35
          ], 
          [
            4.25, 
            0
          ]
        ], 
        "category": "office", 
        "description": "Mobile based company", 
        "sectionname": "xyz", 
        "id": 1
      }, 
      {
        "account": [
          [
            0, 
            3.95
          ], 
          [
            0, 
            7.8
          ], 
          [
            4.25, 
            7.8
          ], 
          [
            4.25, 
            3.95
          ]
        ], 
        "category": "office", 
        "description": "Network based company", 
        "sectionname": "ABC", 
        "id": 2
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "category": "Cowork", 
  "description": "Combined office space"
}
```

You can check your json with http://json.parser.online.fr/ or http://www.bodurov.com/JsonFormatter/.

**Second**, Gson does not like inner classes so much, unless they are declared static.

and **third**: avoid mixing arrays and generics in your classes, generics are safer to use, so I redefined your class as follows:

```
public class AccountData {
   public String uname;
   public String uid;
   public String category;
   public String description;
   public Account account;



   public static class Account {
      public List<Double> entry;
      public List<Double> exit;
      public List<List<Double>> details;
      public List<Section> section;
   }

   public static class Section {
      public List<List<Double>> account;
      public String category;
      public String description;
      public String sectionname;
      public String id;
   }

}
```

If you don't like inner static classes you can always put `Section` and `Account` into separate files (without static keyword, of course).

**EDIT**

As Brian Roach pointed out in comments, it's not needed anymore for inner classes to be static to work well with Gson. So point 2 is no true anymore, you can remove static from your classes declaration.

Comment: Just as an FYI, Gson has no problem with non-static inner classes. Other than that, spot on.

Comment: @BrianRoach, please take a look at https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Nested-Classes-including-Inner-Classes- I'm referring to that part of documentation

Comment: Yes, I know what their docs say there. And their docs are out of date ;) If you test it with the current version of Gson you'll find it now handles even private non-static inner classes.

Comment: Interesting, going to do some tests and look at source...and if it's OK edit a bunch of answers :\ thanks for the clarification

Comment: Yep, I tested and it's like you said. Thanks for the clarification. Going to edit my previous answers starting from this.

Comment: No worries. I honestly don't know what version they changed it but I happened to just do it one day and it worked without issue.

Comment: As this: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=534&q=static%20inner%20classes, you can deserialize no-static inner classes BUT you cannot access to outer instance. This makes the instance "equivalent" to a static one (no outer class available)